# how get last week date record based on current week date

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hi Everyone i am created two mysql query using union join together, based on first  query date parameter get that week and pervious week record which i have add on sample query, but i want get record if select date like '2022-05-23' to '2022-05-26'  get this date record means 3 days record get and base on this get previous week 3 days record, how can this possible pls help me out.

[query sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=dca99a82cd4716a4b878eb6e5cad93aa)

**current query**

```
SELECT dd.date, COUNT(DISTINCT dd.car_number) as total_cars, sum(dd.trips) as total_trips
FROM driver_daily as dd
WHERE dd.team_id= 1 and dd.date BETWEEN '2022-05-23' and '2022-05-29'
                               
UNION
SELECT dd.date, COUNT(DISTINCT dd.car_number) as total_cars, sum(dd.trips) as total_trips                      
FROM driver_daily as dd
WHERE dd.team_id= 1
and (dd.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( '2022-05-23', INTERVAL 7 DAY) and DATE_SUB( '2022-05-29', INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

Comment: Could you please describe more precise what exactly is your problem? To go one week back can be done with something like DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)

Comment: if i  select date between 2 days, how to get previous week 2 days record, also i have added my qus.

Comment: Please either describe your issue more clear or provide sample input and expected outcome as tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATE_ADD function

DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL value addunit)

Comment: i have not issue on current week record, if i select 2 days two how to get previous week 2 days record